# 404 status when displaying `Document is empty` message?

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have a static and content/document driven nuxt 3 blog.

It has some placeholder markdown files under `/content/` that just have their front-matter filled out. For example:

```
---
title: 'Example Title'
description: 'Example Desc'
navigation:
  title: 'Resources'
  bg: 'white'
---
```

When I go to to the above example, `example.com/tester`, it displays this error/msg but still returns a `200` status code.

```
Document is empty

Add content to it by opening content/4.tester/index.md file.
```

How can I get nuxt to return a 404 status code whenever this `Document is empty` error/msg shows up?

Comment: What if you rename it to `tester` rather than `4.tester`?

Comment: @kissu That doesn't change anything. The number at the beginning is just related to navigation ordering.

Comment: How do you generate it and where do you host? Does the generation work locally?